# How to delete all files in a firebase storage directory

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have a firebase storage path that looks like this.

`firebase.storage().ref('temp/test')`

the "test" folder has about 25-50 files. I know there is not a way to delete the whole directory in firebase but Is there a way to iterate through all the files in a directory and deleting them one by one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a way to iterate through all the files in a directory and
> deleting them one by one?

Yes, you can use the [`listAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#list_all_files) method, as follows:

```
  const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('temp');
  storageRef.listAll().then((listResults) => {
    const promises = listResults.items.map((item) => {
      return item.delete();
    });
    Promise.all(promises);
  });
```

Note that:

1. This method is only available for Firebase Rules Version 2 (add `rules_version = '2';` at the top of the Security Rules).
2. This is a helper method for calling `list()` repeatedly until there are no more results. **The default pagination size is 1000**.