# Is there any way to delete a folder of images from firebase storage

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js

I tried this:

```
methods: {
    async deleteCard(mediaRef) {
      // mediaRef is equal to reference of the images folder
      await this.$fire.storage.ref('albums_cards').child(mediaRef).delete()
    },
  },
```

error:

Firebase Storage: Object 'albums_cards/**88b8f000-6dd0-11ed-9c2d-afa013ab0c4b**' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)

but as you see in the picture it exists. I think the method which I used is to delete specific file, but I want to delete folder.

Is there any way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you check my answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `firebase` doesn’t support deleting directories and it is a known issue. You can only delete individual files. So, it's best to store a reference to those files and remove them one by one.

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459200/18265570) `Firebase Storage` does not work with folders. Folders actually don't exist, only files. You can upload files to a specific location/path but their entire filesystem is closer to a flat hash table where you store path/file pairs, than to a file system with multiple folder levels.

You can check the following links for deleting files individually: [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37749647/18265570), [link2](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/757) and [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63434900/18265570)